# Git ignoring a directory without .gitignore

Tags: git

I placed a project folder inside another project folder and naturally git ignored it because it had a `.git` folder inside.

I removed the `.git` folder inside the second project so that it won't be ignored.

However, git still ignores it. I can change the name of the folder and then it's fine. But I want to keep the name the same.

Since there is no `.gitignore` file and the `exclude` file is also empty, I'm assuming that it's being ignored somewhere else.

Using `grep` to search for the folder name in the git files, it comes up in `.git/index` but the file can't be edited.

How can I remove the ignored directory name from my git project?

Comment: Is the subfolder empty?

Comment: Are your files listed when you do `git status --ignored`, but not when you do `git status`?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way a non-empty subfolder is ignored unless you  ignore it in the main git project, even if this subfolder contains a .git .

Comment: @ckruczek No, the subfolder has php files inside, the folder itself gets uploaded to github but is empty inside. When I change the name of the folder all the contents get uploaded just fine.

Comment: @Vampire Nope, it doesn't come up.

Comment: @smarber there is, you can maintain ignore information per user and per system, not only per repository or per clone.

Comment: @smarber All I did was place that subfolder inside my git project. Then `git add .` then `git commit -m 'message'` and `git push origin master` and on github the folder is empty.

Comment: @Danchm01 well, then it is not ignored by Git means. What do you mean by "it gets uploade to GitHub but is empty"? This is not possible you technically **cannot** add an empty directory to Git, you can only add content that is stored in files, but no empty directories.

Comment: @Vampire This is what happens: https://github.com/dchmie01/Portfolio_website/tree/master/projects the folder called `registerphp` gets uploaded normally but when I call it the old name `phpregister` it gets uploaded as 'image' and when I clone the whole project its just an empty directory.

Comment: @Vampire Actually the 'image' is just the name of the commit, my bad. But the issue is still the same. The folder is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added this project as submodule to your project as you can see at https://github.com/dchmie01/Portfolio_website/commit/ce5ed2d3d9776da0acd0244112e7b13e01682e25. You have to remove the project as submodule to be able to add the files directly to the project.

If you want to know how, search here, this question already has answers on SO.

Comment: Although the answer isn't very helpful. I managed to fix the problem by deleting `.git` inside the subdirectory. And using `git rm --cached /path/to/directory` to remove the folder from the cache. The directory wasn't an actual submodule because there was no `.gitmodules` file anywhere and all the `git submodule` commands didn't work. But I don't think there are going to be any other answers so I'll accept this one.